# How to debug with gdb when you are not familiar with function internal implementation?

Tags: c++, gdb

Recently, I encountered a bug where the `std::sort` function crashed. After debugging, I found out that `std::sort` requires the provided comparison function to satisfy strict weak ordering. How can we locate and debug these types of problems using GDB when we are not familiar with the internal implementation? Do we need to know advanced GDB techniques such as viewing assembly commands, registers, or memory?

Comment: Just don't give up, it takes practice. I debug into unknown code all the time, mostly focusing on the callstack and trying to reason back to what could be wrong with my input (you can safely assume for now that the std::sort implementation is correct). If you suspect something is wrong with your comarison function then make unit tests for that (try to let it fail on purpose).

Comment: If you want to debug your comparison function, then set a breakpoint in it. Don't try to debug `std::sort` itself, you can be sure of that it works. Well, it works when using a proper comparison function that follows [the expected rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). If `std::sort` doesn't do what you expect, then it's an error in your comparison function, or in your expectations. So please ask us about the problem you actually have, the reson behind your (mistook) need to debug `std::sort`.

Comment: `std::sort` is a template function so it's code is in a header file and available for you to examine. I'm not very familiar with gdb but I would expect that gdb will also be aware of the `std::sort` code and so you should be able to step through the code and examine variables as you go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get used to black box functions that crash when not used correctly. You need to read the docs of the functions you use: en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort and en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare and follow them closely

The first links the second which clearly states:

> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of a type satisfying Compare, when contextually converted to bool, yields true if the first argument of the call appears before the second in the strict weak ordering relation induced by this type, and false otherwise.

Don't expect that much of the code you call will have any non-optimized-asm view into what it's doing.   Read the docs.